# Is using one Amazon Document DB replica provide fastest fail over time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Because there is no election involved in the fail over, so when the primary is down, it will auto switch to the only one slave automatically?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is within the docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/replication.html

Specifically :

> If a failure occurs in the primary instance (AZ1), a failover is triggered, and one of the existing replicas is promoted to primary. When the old primary recovers, it becomes a replica in the same Availability Zone in which it was provisioned (AZ1). When you provision a three-instance cluster, Amazon DocumentDB continues to preserve that three-instance cluster. Amazon DocumentDB automatically handles detection, failover, and recovery of instance failures without any manual intervention.

and

> You can specify Amazon DocumentDB replicas as failover targets. That is, if the primary instance fails, the specified Amazon DocumentDB replica or replica from a tier is promoted to the primary instance. There is a brief interruption during which read and write requests made to the primary instance fail with an exception. If your Amazon DocumentDB cluster doesn't include any Amazon DocumentDB replicas, when the primary instance fails, it is re-created. Promoting an Amazon DocumentDB replica is much faster than re-creating the primary instance.

Read more about fault tolerance here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/db-cluster-fault-tolerance.html